# CSS how to have position absolute child visible outside of parent with overflow: hidden;

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element `.box` with `overflow: hidden;`

I have a child element `.segment` which has an `::after`

I need to position `::after` outside of `.box` but still be able to see it even though `.box` is `overflow: hidden;`

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="segment">
        ::after            // This ::after is displayed outside of the parent but isn't visible because of `overflow: hidden;`
    </div>
</div>
```

`.box` needs to be `overflow: hidden;` so that the parents `border-radius` is shown.

CSS for ::after

```
.segment::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: ...
}
```

Here is JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o73ft5k2/

Does anyone know how I can keep `overflow: hidden;` so border radius works but also allow the `::after` pseudo-element to appear outside of the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it if the `overflow:hidden` is in place. There is a better way to achieve the same effect without using `overflow:hidden` as it is just not needed to achieve this effect. Check this updated jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/o73ft5k2/1/

You can simply apply `border-radius` on particular elements. Also, notice `box-sizing: border-box" on an after element as padding had to be added for the text to align properly.

Comment: This would work however the contents inside will dynamically be created and it might not be as simple as two elements side by side one with a border on the left on one with a border on the right. For now though I should be able to use `:first-child` and `:last-child`, although this may not be possible in the future.

Comment: I actually was building a similar style menu at work today. It also was rounded on both sides and there would be either three or two or just one element.

In cas of 2 or 3 elements, `first-child` and `last-child` work great, but what if there is only 1 element?

I think it was the first time ever when I used `:only-child` property which basically applied `border-radius` on both sides of a button, only if it was the only one element in a container.

Comment: Yeah that would work too but what I am doing is using `border-radius-top-left` and `border-radius-bottom-left` for the left side and the other way around for the right side. Doing it like that you only have to use `:first-child` and `:last-child`, there is no need for `:only-child`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, you can't. You would need to apply the `border-radius` to the elements instead of the parent in this case.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  background: white;
  padding: 40px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  /*border-radius: 30px;*/
  color: white;
}

.segment {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.segment:first-child, .segment:first-child:after {
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

.segment:last-child, .segment:last-child:after {
  border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.segment:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.segment:hover::after {
  content: 'hello world!';
  color: white;
  top: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="segment red">
        curved border
    </div>
    <div class="segment blue">
        hover broken
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct, you can't because using `overflow: hidden;` will hide any overflow regardless of anything else.